# Populating a new field in a table using data from another table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing

Looking for information on copying the values in a field from on attribute table and pasting them in another table. Both have the same amount of entries and matching ID fields. Should be pretty straightforward but cannot seem to get it to work. On ArcGIS 10.2 with advanced license.

very similar question to what was asked a couple years ago here but original data is in another table than the destination: [Adding new field in ArcMap from data of existing field?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29324/adding-a-new-field-in-arcmap-from-data-of-an-existing-field)

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [Join Field (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000) tool will join your tables. From there you can export your newly joined table and have a new table containing the fields you need. Or, you can use 'Field Calculator' and populate a newly created field, or an existing field, with the attributes from the joined table that you need.

Also, make sure the newly created field has a field-type that is able to be populated from the joined field. Integer-Integer, String-String and so forth

Comment: thanks @Maksim. how exactly would you do this using the field calculator if the fields are in different tables?

Comment: right click the field you want to populate, select Field Calculator. From there you can use VP Script or Python parser, select the field from the different table, and populate your field in the original table

Comment: I mean, is there some particular code to select the field from the other table - the only ones in the "field:" box are from the same table

Comment: If they are successfully joined, your 'Fields:' box should contain all of the fields, prefixed by the table name. Table.OBJECTID and NewTable.OBJECTID for example

Comment: oh right got it i was looking for a way to do it without joining the tables - not possible right?

Comment: Perhaps Append is what you are looking for. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000050000000